# Strange Behavior Of UIColor As Function Parameter In Swift

Tags: swift, function, parameter-passing, uicolor

I've created a function with variable number of parameteres. This is my function:

```
func setColors(colors: UIColor...) {
    self.Colors = colors
}
```

Now when I pass some values to it:

```
setColors(UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.redColor())
```

The black color will be white color in the function. This thing only happens to black color, Other colors work fine.

This thing is used in a class to generate gradients:

```
var Colors: [UIColor] = []

func setColors(colors: UIColor...) {
    self.Colors = colors
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let colorSpace: CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var colorComponent: [CGFloat] = []
    var colorLocations: [CGFloat] = []
    var i: CGFloat = 0.0;

    for color in Colors {
        let c = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor)
        colorComponent.append(c[0])
        colorComponent.append(c[1])
        colorComponent.append(c[2])
        colorComponent.append(c[3])
        colorLocations.append(i)
        i += CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(self.Colors.count)
    }

    let gradient: CGGradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colorComponent, colorLocations, self.Colors.count)

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.size.height / 2), CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height / 2), 0)
}
```

Comment: Not so. You're just misreading the output.

Comment: @matt No I'm Using This Function To Create A Gradient In Core Graphics. The Result Is White Color

Comment: I doubt it. You can't create a gradient from a UIColor. Your code elsewhere is going wrong because you don't derive the CGColor correctly from this color. So your problem is elsewhere. But I answered (correctly) the question you actually asked. If you asked the wrong question, ask a different question.

Comment: I use `color.CGColor` to use in the gradient. As I said the gradient is fine but the black color, appears white in the result.

Comment: But you don't show that code so I don't believe you're doing it right. You might be configuing the gradient incorrectly. I have no way of knowing. I only know what you tell me. From what you've told me, this is just a matter of misreading the output. You didn't ask about any gradient. You claimed the black color would be white _in this function_. I proved you're wrong about that. That's the end of that. I ran _your code_. I got the _right answer_. Done.

Comment: @matt so let me edit the question

Comment: You're not wrong @matt, but there's no need to be a jerk about it. "When I run this code it seems like the color is set correctly, so I would say that the issue is somewhere else. If you post the code where this function is used, I would be happy to look at it and help you out." Much better.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020420/cgcolorgetcomponents-not-returning-the-correct-values-for-black-and-for-white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var colors: [UIColor] = []

func setColors(colors: UIColor...) {
    self.colors = colors
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let colorSpace: CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var gradientColors: [CGColor] = []
    var colorLocations: [CGFloat] = []
    var i: CGFloat = 0.0;

    for color in colors {
        gradientColors.append(color.CGColor)
        colorLocations.append(i)
        i += CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(colors.count)
    }

    let gradient: CGGradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, gradientColors, colorLocations)

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.size.height / 2), CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height / 2), 0)
}
```

Side Note: You don't want to capitalize variable names. So I changed `self.Colors` to `self.colors`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `CGColorGetComponents` wrong:

```
let c = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor)
colorComponent.append(c[0])
colorComponent.append(c[1])
colorComponent.append(c[2])
colorComponent.append(c[3])
```

You're making a false assumption here.

That code *happens* to work *if* this color is in the UIDeviceRGBColorSpace, which has four components.

But it does *not* work if this color in the UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace, which has just *two* components - and black *is* in the UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace.

Comment: No you don't. You have an rgb `colorSpace` variable but you don't use it until _after_ you have incorrectly extracted the components. By then, it's too late - you've got the wrong components. You need to respond to the _actual_ color space of the actual colors. There is also a function that tells you how many components it really has.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. Your code makes no sense to me. Why are you extracting components at all? Just call `CGGradientCreateWithColors` and you're all set.

Comment: I want to create a gradient. What should I do?

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you. I answered the question you asked (again). Read what I've said. Read the other answer I linked you to. Read my comments. Read the docs!